# jptionpane to read the yes or no actions

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, joptionpane

I need to popup some one dialog and get the user confirmation .
and I want this dailog should be always top , till user select yes or No option .
below is the program I wrote , but now how to get which option has user selected .. 
i.e Yes or NO ..?

```
JFrame parent = new JFrame();
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("DO you want to continue?",         JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
JDialog  dialog = null ;

dialog = optionPane.createDialog(parent, "Next Job process");
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read [`JOptionPane`'s documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)?

There are two ways to use it. One way is to use the various static methods that already return the user's choice or input.

The other way is a *direct use* (mentioned in the documentation). Once you created a `JOptionPane`, you can configure it with various `setX` methods. Then you retrieve a JDialog instance, as you already did. After that dialog is close, you can retrieve the user's choice or input with

```
optionPane.getValue()
```

or

```
optionPane.getInputValue()
```

Answer (score 5):

`JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION` return `int` value

you may try:

```
int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                       "Do you want to continue?", 
                       null, 
                       JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 

if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    //do something
}
else{ //user choose 'No'
    //do something
}
```

Comment: yes I tried this , but I want this optionpane to be always on the top !!! .. so I tried with Jdailog.

Comment: @RafaEl I think the OP's problem would be fixed by changing `"Do you want to continue?", null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);` to `"Do you want to continue?", this, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);` where `this` represents the 'parent component' that the OP wishes to modally block..